# this is concerning PHP and form validations

Tags: php, validation

bellow you see my form validation script that I have been working on for a while. The script is suppose to check if the "Name:" is first not empty and then if it only contains letters and then insert the data. Likewise for the "Price:" it is suppose to check if it is not empty and then it's only digits. So far I have failed to make all the functions working and here are the problems as it sits right now:

- in general it does not insert data to the table
- regardless says price is required (even if the price is given)
- when there is given numbers in the name field, there is no error

and here is the script:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML> 
<html>
<head>
<style>
.error {color: #FF0000;}
</style>
</head>
<body> 

<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","xxxxx","xxxxx","my_project");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) 
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
} 
// define variables and set to empty values
$nameErr = $priceErr = $catErr = $condErr = $regionErr = "";
$product_name = $product_price = $product_cat = $product_cond = $product_region = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") 
{
   if (empty($_POST["product_name"])) 
   {
     $nameErr = "Name is required";

   }
    else if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$product_name)) 
     {
       $nameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
     }

    if (empty ($_POST ["product_price"]))
   {
       $priceErr = "Price is required";
   }
   else if(!ctype_digit($product_price))
    {
     $priceErr = "Price is required";
    } 

   else 
   {
    $product_name = test_input($_POST["product_name"]);
    $product_price = test_input($_POST["product_price"]);
    $sql= "INSERT INTO Product (product_name, product_cond, product_price, product_cat, product_region, email, phone_num)
          VALUES
          ('$_POST[product_name]','$_POST[product_cond]','$_POST[product_price]','$_POST[product_cat]','$_POST[product_region]','$_POST[Email]','$_POST[PhoneNumber]')";

     if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) 
    {
        echo 'Error: ' . mysqli_error($con);
    }
    else     
    {
        echo "1 record added";
    }

mysqli_close($con);

}

}


function test_input($data) {
   $data = trim($data);
   $data = stripslashes($data);
   $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
   return $data;
}
?>

<h2>PHP Form Validation Example</h2>
<p><span class="error">* required field.</span></p>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>"> 
   Name: <input type="text" name="product_name" value="<?php echo $product_name;?>">
   <span class="error">* <?php echo $nameErr;?></span>
   <br><br>
   price: <input type="text" name="product_price" value="<?php echo $product_price;?>">
   <span class="error">* <?php echo $priceErr;?></span>
   <br><br>

   Condition: 
      <select name="product_cond" required  >
      <option value="" >SELECT</option>
      <option value="Used" >Used </option>
      <option value="new" >New</option>

</select>

   Category:
  <select name="product_cat" required >
  <option value="" >SELECT</option>
  <option value="books" >books</option>
  <option value="Computers" >Computers</option>
  <option value="Hardware/Tools" >Hardware/Tools </option>
  <option value="Cars" >Cars</option>
  <option value="home Appliances" >home Appliances</option>
  </select>

Region:
<select name="product_region" required >
  <option value="" >SELECT</option>
  <option value="Oulu" >Oulu</option>
  <option value="Turku" >Turku</option>
  <option value="Helsinki" >Helsinki </option>
  <option value="Tornio" >Vaasa</option>
  <option value="Tampere" >Tampere</option>
  <option value="Kemi" >Kemi</option>

  <input type="submit">
</form>



</body>
```

and here is the example that I have used and modified:

http://www.w3schools.com/php/showphp.asp?filename=demo_form_validation_special

Comment: So far I have tried putting the else if statements inside the if statements but it didn't work

Comment: look at this line `else if(!ctype_digit($product_price))` it should like `else if(!ctype_digit($_POST['product_price']))`. With `ctype_digit` with floats (ie. 9.99). Why not to use `is_numeric` ?

Comment: @soyale I used bunch of stuff with preg_match() non of which worked. I think it has more to do with the structure of the script

Comment: Your sql statement is wrong. And the rest is a mess, too. Have a look at all the ifs and elses.

Comment: @user3463859 in your current code you will never reach sql statement. Because you have use wrong argument in `ctype_digit`. `$product_name` instead of `$_POST ["product_price"]`

Comment: Yikes - that W3Schools script is in a right state, especially the `test_input` function, which does all manner of escaping without actually using the right escaping method, or using parameterisation! I'd be tempted to recommend you don't use this site.

Comment: You are using `$product_name` and `$product_price` in your regex tests even though you've only set them to the empty string.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to use an array of errors instead of variables.

Then you should access the variables you send by the form like `$_POST['variable']`

Try this code:

```
$errors =  array();
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    if (empty($_POST["product_name"])) {
        $errors['name'] = "Name is required";
    } else if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/", $_POST['product_name'])) {
        $errors['name'] = "Only letters and white space allowed";
    }

    if (empty($_POST ["product_price"])) {
        $errors['price'] = "Price is required";
    } else if (!ctype_digit($_POST['product_price'])) {
        $errors['price'] = "Price is required";
    }

    if(count($errors) == 0){
        $product_name = test_input($_POST["product_name"]);
        $product_price = test_input($_POST["product_price"]);
        $sql = "INSERT INTO Product (product_name, product_cond, product_price, product_cat, product_region, email, phone_num)
  VALUES
  ('$_POST[product_name]','$_POST[product_cond]','$_POST[product_price]','$_POST[product_cat]','$_POST[product_region]','$_POST[Email]','$_POST[PhoneNumber]')";

        if (!mysqli_query($con, $sql)) {
            echo 'Error: ' . mysqli_error($con);
        } else {
            echo "1 record added";
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: thank you for your ans but this still does not work. It does not give me an error when I leave the fields empty or write the wrong data type